# fermentor vs. fermenter

Tags: feature-request, retagging

There are only 4 tags that use the word fermenter, and none for fermentor.  However, the word fermenter is being used incorrectly.

Yeast is a fermenter.
Carboys, conicals, and buckets are fermentors.

I don't have complete edit control to fix it.  Or maybe I am not doing it right.
A moderator or someone with full con

Comment: Why do you think fermenter is not the correct usage describing a container? I personally don't know for sure what is correct but I'd be interested in seeing some more documentation

Comment: I've asked on the English site: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/31547/766

Comment: Glad this is cleared up. I need to edit my posts!

Answer (score 1):

I have used "fermenter" as a term for carboy etc... and have no issue with it. I feel that there may be some confusion if we try and split this term, but am generally ambivalent about this terminology and will support whichever side is preferred by the majority.

Comment: I think precision/correctness is always the best side on which to err. While I'm not sure many people will notice the distinction, it's good practice to use the language correctly even if a lot of people don't - just as we do with grammar, for example. Just because a lot of people use something wrongly doesn't make it a truly valid or correct option, any more than "thx 4 ur hlp m8" is proper English just because a lot of people butcher it that way.

Comment: Agree with Kathryn. We should aim for precision "even in homebrewing".

Comment: Too bad that here isn't a way to link the two so that if the person doesn't understand the distinction/misspells, they still end up with relevant information.